# Click event not work in selenium webdriver in java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using java with selenium webdriver while run

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='releasesdiv']/select[@id='releaseID']")).click();
```

No exception occur but the click event is not trigger. If any suggestion to how to overcome this problem? thanks in advance.
Note : xpath perfect (No doubt).

Comment: If there has been no exception then it means the click has happened. May be you are clicking on to something that has no outcome. If you are planning to select from drop down you should use `Select` in WebDriver.

Comment: problem get fixed by change driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS); to Thread.sleep(3000);  I am wondered.... what is the difference between thread sleep and implicitlyWait?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in short, implicity wait, waits until the specified maximum time if they are(elements) not immediate available. if the element is available on the page with in the specified max time, its start execution and continue the specified actions on that element. Some times webdriver performs specified action on the element correctly but it will not triggered or simulated correctly. that's the reason we did not get exception here.. In these situations Thread.sleep which is java command helps. It will blindly wait up to specified time with out considering the element is available or not in specified time.

http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thread.sleep(10)means your program will not execute for a specified period of time eg 10 sec. 
Implicit wait of 3 sec means  webdriver will poll the webelement after every 250ms till 3 sec to appear and if it finds the webelement the webdriver will continue  execute the next script otherwise Nosuchelementexception